# Using @AppStorage for user sign in flow?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

Issue = View does not change after log_Status = true

I am trying to take the user to a different view after the user has signed in. I have implemented Sign in with Apple and Sign in with Google into my project. For this question, I will showcase Sign in with Google code.

```
@AppStorage("log_Status") var log_Status = false
```

Has been set into the corresponding files.

After the user clicks on the sign in with google button and the user logs in, see below:

// handle Sign in...

```
func handleSignin() {
    
    // Google Sign in...
    
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
    
    // Create Google Sign In configuration object.
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) { [self] user, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            
            return
        }
        
        guard
            let authentication = user?.authentication,
            let idToken = authentication.idToken
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        // Firebase Auth...
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, err in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            //Displaying User Name...
            guard let user = result?.user else {
                return
            }
            
            print(user.displayName ?? "Success!")
            
            // Updating User as Logged in
            withAnimation {
                log_Status = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, an If statement has been created in order to take the user to a different View using var log_Status.

```
struct AccountView: View {

    @AppStorage("log_Status") var log_Status = false

    var body: some View {
        
        if log_Status {
            
            ContentView()
            
            NavigationView {
                Button("Log Out") {
                    // Apple Loging out User...
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                    }
        
                    // Google Loging out User...
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signOut()
                    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                    

                   // Updating log_status = true
                    withAnimation {
                        log_Status = false
        } else { 
            SignInScreenView()
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody has any idea of why the view does not change or if I am implementing @AppStorage in the wrong manner please let me know.

If more information is required feel free to ask. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the first part of the if statement, you create 2 separate views: a `ContentView()` and then a `Button` which will not show on the same screen. If you want them together, you have to put them in some other `View` or `Stack`. Also, you should only use one `NavigationView` at the top of your first view, not just around the `Button`. Lastly, in Swift, the convention is to use camelCase for variables, not snake_case.

Comment: Please provide a working example of your code, that reproduces the issue. This will improve the chances of helpful answers significantly.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is having issues with this. This is what Apple told me:

> If you need to access it "outside" the views, it is better to place the @AppStorage somewhere higher in the view hierarchy and pass it with bindings.
>
> There are two approaches to using @AppStorage property wrapper, and sharing it around your app -
>
> 1. Send the app storage value around other views using @Bindings.
> 2. Send the app storage value around other views using “.environment".
>
> I prefer #2, as it's slightly easer to use and more flexible. Here is an example of #2, which will require an `EnvironmentKey` and extension to `EnvironmentValues`.
>
> ```
> struct CustomTextKey: EnvironmentKey {
>     static var defaultValue: Binding<String> = >Binding.constant("Default Text")
> }
> extension EnvironmentValues {
>     var customText: Binding<String> {
>         get { self[CustomTextKey.self] }
>         set { self[CustomTextKey.self] = newValue }
>     }
> }
> struct ContentView: View {
>     @AppStorage("text") private var text: String = ""
>     
>     var body: some View {
>         TextEditor(text: $text).padding()
>         Divider()
>         SecondView()
>             .environment(\.customText, $text)
>     }
> }
> struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
>     static var previews: some View {
>         ContentView()
>     }
> }
> struct SecondView: View {
>     var body: some View {
>         ThirdView()
>     }
> }
> struct ThirdView: View {
>     @Environment(\.customText) private var text: Binding<String>
>     var body: some View {
>        TextEditor(text: text).padding()
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Remember, you define your `@AppStorage` in only one place as the single source of truth, and pass it around to other views accordingly.

I will try to implement `@Bindings` since I find it easier.

Comment: No problem, Jeff.  I’ve updated your answer to clarify what came from Apple and what was original content. Please let me know if I made any mistakes (or [edit] your answer to correct them).